# Struts property not getting action model

Tags: java, jsp, struts

im new to struts/java. Im currently trying to get a value from an Action class model. my java code to populate the model is

```
public String index() {
    EvaluationModel model = new EvaluationModel();
    EvaluationService eval = new EvaluationService();
    try {

        model = eval.getpersonalInfo((String)getSessionAttribute("emplId"));


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return SUCCESS;

}
```

i already debugged and im sure that the model is returning a value. The model contains submodels so im calling it in jsp like this (well, i tried all of these, and nothing is working;

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                        <c:out value="${request.model.employee.empldId}" />
                        <c:out value="${request.model.employee.getEmpldId()}" />
                        <s:property value="#model.employee.empldId" />
                        <s:property value="model.employee.empldId" />
                        <s:property value="%{request.model.employee.empldId}" />
                        <s:property value="%{request.model.employee.getEmpldId()}" />
                    </div>
```

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: also tried this and it is not working <s:property
          value="#request.model.employee.empldId" />

Comment: There's nothing being exposed to the JSP here; you have a local value that you promptly throw away.